# UIStackView has no useful ReadableContentGuide

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I am adding SubViews to a vertical UIStackView with AddArrangedSubView. By default those views are positioned at the Left and Right edges.

I can set

```
LayoutMargins = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15),
LayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
```

And that will give me 15px of Left and Right Padding. That's great but what I really want is for the Left and Right padding to be controlled by the [ReadableContentGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622644-readablecontentguide). This works perfectly on a `UITableView` and the property is available on `UIStackView` however it has margins of 0.

How can I get a `UILayoutGuide` that has the right values for the current device and orientation?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug in UIStacView (width:200 , height 110 ) from log

```
- "UIViewReadableContentGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {200, 110}}, owningView = <UIStackView: 0x10380afc0; frame = (87.5 146; 200 110); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CATransformLayer: 0x1c4028de0>>>
```

when log UITextView (width:240 , height 128 )

```
-  "UIViewReadableContentGuide", layoutFrame = {{8, 8}, {224, 112}}, owningView = <UITextView: 0x103002a00; frame = (67.5 279.5; 240 128); text = 'Some html string '; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c4458450>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4034440>;
```

Comment: Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: I tried the latter by adding a with a throwaway UILabel and tried reading the LayoutGuide on it but it was 0. I am guessing it does not become useful until full layout. I'll try examining the values later in the layout cycle

Comment: use it with throwaway textView it will return values

Comment: Sorry being an idiot. I meant UITextView. Added one to ArrangedSubview and it was 0. Will get back soon